# Use of 'CONTAINS(Foo, "A") OR CONTAINS(Foo, "B") vs CONTAINS(Foo, '"A" OR "B"') in SQL Server FullText

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I need to find some texts in a pretty huge database full text indexed, and i dont know what is better to use in my variations of the terms in the query.

I have saw some examples using

```
SELECT
    Foo.Bar
FROM
    Foo
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(Foo.Bar, "A") OR 
    CONTAINS(Foo.Bar, "B")
```

And some examples using

```
SELECT 
    Foo.Bar
FROM 
    Foo
WHERE 
    CONTAINS(Foo.Bar, '"A" OR "B"')
```

What is better to use? And why?

Comment: better how? Faster? Probably best to just do some testing yourself to compare.

Comment: The goal is faster, but my question was in general (faster, uses less ram, cpu etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consolidating calls to CONTAINS (your 2nd example) is going to require less work. There is some overhead involved with each CONTAINS predicate, like the compilation of the full text query, that can be limited. This is one of the recommendations made on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879244(v=sql.120).aspx).

With that said, the difference may be negligible based on a number of factors like the index size, the query, the number of documents that contain the words in your query...